# Ban direct access to a php file but not for cron job

Tags: php, .htaccess, cron

I have a php file that sends curl and saves the data in the database, and I need to run this script daily, but I want only cron job to execute that PHP file, not anybody else.

I could use a piece of advice.
Thanks

Comment: You could use the [php_sapi_name function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) and stop execution if the response is not `cli`.

Comment: I would probably do this too just for safety reasons.

Comment: Keep the php script outside the section of the server side file system that is published via the http server. And execute it using the php cli interface, not using the http server via a curl call. That offers a strict separation of both worlds. You need to take care of permissions though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming linux, if it's in your home dir and you are the owner, and you didn't chmod 777 it, it should be okay.

If your questions is how to prevent people from opening the php file externally from the browser, don't place it in /var/html or whatever your webserver directory is.

Comment: A file permission pattern of `0777`? For a php script? That could only make sense if you also place a shebang at the beginning of a file...

Comment: And whether "it should be ok" if the file is in someone's home folder actually depends on the setup of the http server, so the configuration. Doesn't it? Many http server setups use the use module for example to publish parts of the user's home folder. Which would make the setup "not ok"...